# My rechargeable Ni-MH AA batteries went through the wash in my pocket! Are they safe to use?

Tags: batteries, damage

I havent used them yet, but I'm getting the impression they will be fine to recharge and use after they dry out.  Is this true?

Comment: +1 I always wondered this myself. I never had problems using batteries in water, but I really don't know what washing could have done.

Comment: Don't dry them with hot air or anything -- just some desiccant.

Answer (score 3):

Most batteries and cells are fairly well sealed. They'll be fine. You might want to clean off the terminals to ensure they don't corrode during normal use, but otherwise they should work.

Answer (score 1):

The only answer is probably.

Just keep an eye on them while charging and using for the first time.
That's the only way to be sure.